# Short story about intergalactic pizza delivery via time travel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, space

I am looking for the name/title of this short story (not a book) with the following plot/elements:

- An intergalactic pizza delivery service run by a family
- The pizza kitchen never stops ("the mad rush")
- The orders come in all the time, and to make all the deliveries in time, they travel through time
- During one delivery, the deliveryman met the love of his life, who became the lady boss of this business.

It is not "Zorgoochi Intergalactic Pizza".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Possibly [Pizza to Go by Tom Holt](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?379351).

It starts at the feeding of the five thousand where:

> "I see," said Jesus Christ. "You forgot to tell them to bring sandwiches."
>
> "It's Peter's fault," said Barnabas pre-emptively. "I asked him what we were going to do about catering, and he said no worries, he had a mate who could give us a really special price - "
>
> "We're going to get lynched," John groaned. "There'll be little bits of us scattered about all the way to Caesarea."
>
> "Don't be silly," said the Messiah. "Leave this to me. Honestly, if it wasn't for me, I don't know what you'd do." From his sleeve he took a mobile phone and a small piece of card, on which was written:
>
> PIZZA TO GO
> We deliver
> Any time
> Any where

The lady is Bianca di Fiesole who is rescued from Renaissance Italy by the time travelling pizza man (actually a woman) when her entire family is poisened. The story ends:

> Because this is Bianca's kitchen, possibly the most extraordinary place in spacetime. From this small prefabricated industrial unit - well, indeed, skip all that. We may have been here before.
>
> There's Rocco and Tony, who make the bases; Freddy and Mike, who do the toppings; Carlo, who minds the ovens; Rosa and Vito and Zelda, who chop the vegetables and deal with the side-orders; Frankie, Ennio and, of course, young Gino, who do the deliveries; and there's Momma Bianca, who takes the orders, writes out the tickets and does everything.
> Occasionally her eldest daughter Zelda suggests it might help if she were to take a turn answering the phone occasionally, so as to give Momma a break at her age. And Bianca says yeah, that'd be good. As soon as the rush is over.
>
> When people ask her how she copes, Momma Bianca grins. "It's a family business," she says.